# What does it mean for a transfer function matrix to be real, rational, and stable?

Tags: transfer-function

In a book I'm reading, the author writes

> For example, all real rational stable transfer matrices are analytic in the right-half plane

I'm not sure of the definitions of "real", "rational", and "stable" here. I'll mention what I think they mean, but would appreciate any feedback on whether they are right.

Given an $M \times N$ transfer function matrix $\mathbf G(s) = (G_{ij}(s))$, where $G_{ij}(s)$ is the transfer function relating input $j$ to output $i$, here is what I think these words mean:

- "real": for any $s_0 \in \mathbb C$, every element of the matrix $\mathbf G (s_0)$ is real.
- "rational": each transfer function in $\mathbf G(s)$ can be expressed as $G_{ij}(s) = \frac{p(s)}{q(s)}$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials in $s$.
- "stable": all the poles for each transfer function in $\mathbf G(s)$ are in the left-half complex plane.

Are my definitions correct?

Comment: Don't you mean $s_0\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @MattL. No I meant $s_0 \in \mathbb C$. My understanding is that a transfer function matrix $\mathbf G(s)$ can be defined as the function $\mathbf G : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C^{m \times n}$. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: No, but how could it be real for any complex-valued argument?

Comment: @MattL. that makes sense. It seems then that my understanding of "real" is wrong here. Any idea what it could mean instead? I'm thinking that it means that all the poles of each $G_{ij}(s)$ are real, but I'm not sure if that's right.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about all points but the first: "real" here refers to a real-valued system with a transfer function satisfying

$$G(s)\in\mathbb{R}\quad\textrm{for}\quad s\in\mathbb{R}$$

I.e., if $G(s)$ is the ratio of two polynomials then all polynomial coefficients are real-valued. This generalizes to transfer matrices in the obvious way.